# Calculating "first overdue" date from a payment schedule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

**Summary**

I am writing an "Aged debtors" view based on a table of invoices and payments received, with no link between individual payments due and payments received. How can I use SQL to calculate the amount outstanding and oldest unsettled invoice?

**Example**

Invoices

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| CustomerID | AmountDue |  DateDue   |
+------------+-----------+------------+
|          1 |       100 | 2015-02-01 |
|          1 |       100 | 2015-03-01 |
|          1 |       100 | 2015-04-01 |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Payments received

```
+------------+----------------+--------------+
| CustomerID | AmountReceived | DateReceived |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|          1 |             60 | 2015-01-11   |
|          1 |            100 | 2015-02-21   |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Desired output (when run sometime after 2015-04-01)

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| CustomerID | AmountOutstanding | FirstUnsettledInvoice |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|          1 |               140 | 2015-03-01            |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Current output

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| CustomerID | AmountOutstanding | FirstUnsettledInvoice |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|          1 |               140 | 2015-04-01            |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Current query

```
  SELECT TotalPayment.CustomerID, TotalDue - TotalReceived as AmountOutstanding, MaxDueDate as FirstUnsettledInvoice
  FROM 
    (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(AmountReceived) as TotalReceived
    FROM PaymentReceived
    GROUP BY CustomerID) as TotalPayment
  JOIN
    (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(AmountDue) as TotalDue, MAX(DateDue) as MaxDueDate
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE DateDue < GETUTCDATE()
    GROUP BY CustomerID) as TotalInvoice
  ON TotalPayment.CustomerID = TotalInvoice.CustomerID
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show your query, and we might be able to help you figure out why it's not working.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? It affects the answer ...

Comment: You forgot to show the keys

Comment: I'll put together a query (it's a simplified example), but my output was 140 and 2015-04-01. Version is 2014. The important key for all the tables is CustomerID, although each row also has an auto-incrementing key. Is that likely to be a useful column?

Comment: @thelem: How you get FirstUnsettledInvoice - 2015-03-01 ?? I mean how you calculate it ?

Comment: Because I have received $160 from the customer. $100 pays off the first invoice and $60 goes towards the second invoice. That means I am still owed $40 from the second invoice (2015-03-01) and $100 from the final invoice.

Comment: I used to work for software company that did car dealership management so I'm familiar with this process. Is this going to be a stored procedure that pulls information for a single customer?

Comment: No, this is going to be used in a view across the whole database, to identify the customers whose debts should be chased first (either because they are large or have been outstanding for a long time). We need to be able to sort by AmountOutstanding and FirstUnsettledInvoice.

Comment: You need something called a `running total`.   There are many examples on this site and the rest of the internet.   You want the first (or MIN) DateDue where the running total of `Amount Due` is less than the total of `AmountReceived`.   please google and learn about `Running Total in SQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Tab Alleman I've written the following query that gives me the result I'm after:

```
 SELECT CustomerID, MAX(runningtotal) - MAX(TotalReceived), MIN(DateDue) FROM (
      SELECT 
        TotalPayment.CustomerID,
        TotalReceived,
        AmountDue,
        sum(AmountDue) over(order by DateDue rows unbounded preceding) as runningtotal,
        DateDue
      FROM
        Invoice
      JOIN
        (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(AmountReceived) as TotalReceived
        FROM PaymentReceived
        GROUP BY CustomerID) as TotalPayment
      ON TotalPayment.CustomerID = Invoice.CustomerID
) AS subquery
 WHERE subquery.AmountDue < subquery.runningtotal
 Group By CustomerID
```